# SearchView :Triggering onQueryTextChange on Collapsing of the searchView

Tags: android

```
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            search(newText);

            return true;
        }
    });
```

I don't want search(newText) to be executed when `searchview` collapses.

I tried

```
if(searchView.isShown) search(newText);
```

and

```
if(!searchView.isIconified) search(newText);
```

but when I close the `searchview`, `searchView.isShown` and `searchView.isIconified` values will be updated after triggering `onQueryTextChange`.

My onCreateOptionMenu code:

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_contacts, menu);

        addContactMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_add_contact);
        searchViewMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchViewMenuItem);
        MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener(searchViewMenuItem, new MenuItemCompat.OnActionExpandListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {
                addContactMenuItem.setVisible(false);
                if (contactListAdapter != null)
                    contactListAdapter.getFilter().filter(searchView.getQuery());
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item) {
                addContactMenuItem.setVisible(true);
                contactListAdapter.performGroupBasedFiltering(groupSpinner.getAdapter().getItemId(groupSpinner.getSelectedItemPosition()));
                return true;
            }
        });

        return true;
    }
```

Please help me out! Thanks in advance.

Comment: you question is unclear explain more and also add code what did you tried so far

Comment: @Prem I've edited the post trying to explain to an extent. Please help me out!

Comment: share your oncreateotion menu code()

Comment: check my below ans

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this use [**`setOnActionExpandListener`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuItem.html#setOnActionExpandListener(android.view.MenuItem.OnActionExpandListener))

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.search_menu, menu);

        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);

               MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener(item,
            new MenuItemCompat.OnActionExpandListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem menuItem) {
                    // perform your action here 
                    return true;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem menuItem) {
                    // perform your action here 
                    return true;
                }
            });




        return true;

    }
```

**EDIT**

**[as per your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47546312/searchview-triggering-onquerytextchange-on-collapsing-of-the-searchview/47546699?noredirect=1#comment82050029_47546699)**

**I need `search(newText)` not to be executed on collapsing.**

> than set this `searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(null);` when you don't need

Comment: Yeah! I've used that method. But I need search(newText) not to be executed on collapsing. But search(newText) is executing onCollapsing. How can stop it.

Comment: I've updated me question adding the onCreateOptionMenu. Please check that.

Comment: @AkshayKumar **I need search(newText) not to be executed on collapsing.** than set this **`searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(null);`** when you don't need

Comment: I'll try. Thank you :)

Comment: @AkshayKumar let me know if any query

Comment: @AkshayKumar happy to help you